# Concatenate Custom String to column based on another column value in View

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a View in SQL Server where I want Custom String to Concatenate to one of column based on value of another column.

I have Purchase Order Table having fields like Quantity in Unit1 (Bags/Boxes), Quantity in Unit2 (Weight) where order is taken in any one of these and so the selection is stored in another column having name Unit (store value will be 'B for Bags Or 'W' for Weight).

Now I have another column having name Balance Qty which I want to concatenate with ' Bags' if Unit value is 'B' OR with ' K.G.' if Unit Value is 'W'.

what I wrote so far is

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[PurOrderView]
AS
SELECT
           dbo.PurchaseOrders.FYEndYear                                                      AS FY
         , dbo.PurchaseOrders.CompId
         , dbo.PurchaseOrders.InputDevice                                                    AS Dev
         , dbo.PurchaseOrders.POrderID                                                       AS ID
         , dbo.PurchaseOrders.POrderDate                                                     AS [Order Date]
         , dbo.PurchaseOrders.SupplierAccId                                                  AS [Acc Id]
         , dbo.AccountHeads.AccountName                                                      AS Supplier
         , dbo.PurchaseOrders.BrokerId
         , dbo.Brokers.BrokerName                                                            AS Broker
         , dbo.PurchaseOrders.ProductId
         , dbo.Products.ProductName                                                          AS Product
         , dbo.PurchaseOrders.OrderInUnit                                                    AS Unit
         , dbo.PurchaseOrders.BagsBoxes                                                      AS [Bags/Boxes]
         , dbo.PurchaseOrders.StdPacking                                                     AS Packing
         , dbo.PurchaseOrders.ApproxWeightInKG                                               AS Weight
         , dbo.PurchaseOrders.ContractRate                                                   AS Rate
         , CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), dbo.PurchaseOrders.RatePer) + ' kg'                           AS Per
         , dbo.PurchaseOrders.AdjustQtyBy                                                    AS [Adj Qty]
         , CAST(dbo.PurchaseOrders.BalQty AS VARCHAR) + ' ' + dbo.PurchaseOrders.OrderInUnit AS [Balance Qty]
         , dbo.PurchaseOrders.Remark
         , dbo.PurchaseOrders.UserId
         , dbo.PurchaseOrders.EntryDate
FROM       dbo.PurchaseOrders
INNER JOIN dbo.AccountHeads ON dbo.PurchaseOrders.SupplierAccId = dbo.AccountHeads.AccountID
INNER JOIN dbo.Brokers ON dbo.PurchaseOrders.BrokerId           = dbo.Brokers.BrokerID
INNER JOIN dbo.Products ON dbo.PurchaseOrders.ProductId         = dbo.Products.ProductID
```

Here in the statement

```
cast(dbo.PurchaseOrders.BalQty as varchar) + ' ' + dbo.PurchaseOrders.OrderInUnit  AS [Balance Qty]
```

I want to apply condition on OrderInUnit column for custom string instead.

Comment: How about a simplified example .... data sample and desired results

Comment: Please provide Sample data + Expected results (as formatted text). Please layout your SQL query in a readable fashion... its impossible to make sense of that block of text. I highly recommend using table aliases to improve the readability.

Comment: Yes - cram your code together without any useful formatting. That encourages others to reassemble your code while reading to understand it and help you. One thing that is deprecated is using three part names - someone will eventually need to correct this when it becomes a breaking change in some future version.

Comment: Looks to me like you need a [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) expression. Do a little research on that and let us know what you have tried and if you get stuck we can help you from there.

Comment: @Isaac: `CASE` **expression**, not *statement*...

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Aside: Best practice is to _always_ supply a length when using `VarChar` and `NVarChar`.

Comment: Also look into using table aliases, they'll make your life easier

Comment: e.g. in PurchaseOrders Table 2 Columns are there having Records as say 
    OrderInUnit , BalQty

1] B, 100
2] B, 60
3] W, 456.780
4] B, 111
5] W, 1000
6] W, 78.9

Now I want the Result in View to look like

BalQty As Balance Qty
1] 100.000 Bags
2] 60.000 Bags
3] 456.780 K.G.
4] 111.000 Bags
5] 1000.000 K.G.
6] 78.900 K.G.

Comment: @sandeepbj: If you want to add or change something to improve the quality of the question, you shouldn't add comments. [Edit] the question itself instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer as per your suggestion to use CASE expression

I used following

cast(dbo.PurchaseOrders.BalQty as varchar) + ' ' + CASE WHEN dbo.PurchaseOrders.OrderInUnit = 'B' THEN 'Bags' ELSE 'K.G.' END AS [Balance Qty]

Thanks